# Share point E mail domains

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have two company domains on share point. When sending an e mail I want to choose which domain it comes from. How do I set this up?

Comment: could you please explain what you want and in which sharepoint version you are?

Comment: You need to add more details! How is the email sent, do all users have two email addresses, one for each domain etc?